# Check date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I get three variables through a user input, that contain the year of a date, the month and the day. I've already checked if the month var is between 1–12 and so on.

Now I want to check if it's a real date and not a date that doesn't exist like 31–06–2011.

My first idea was to make a new Date instance:

```
var year = 2011;
var month = 5; // five because the months start with 0 in JavaScript - June
var day = 31;
var myDate = new Date(2011,5,31);
console.log(myDate);
```

But myDate doesn't return false, because it's not a valid date. Instead it returns 'Fri Jul 01 2011 [...]'.

Any ideas how I can check for an invalid date?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, dotweb! Please don't put tags in the title, thanks!

Comment: Tags belong in the tags, [not in the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66152/titles-should-the-most-relevant-tag-be-included-in-the-title).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ((myDate.getMonth()+1!=month)||(myDate.getDate()!=day)||(myDate.getFullYear()!=year))
    alert("Date Invalid.");
```

Comment: You only need to check two components, but all three doesn't hurt. :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
if ((myDate.getDate() != day) || 
    (myDate.getMonth() != month - 1) || 
    (myDate.getFullYear() != year))
{
    return false;
}
```

JavaScript just converts entered in `Date` constructor `month`, `year`, `day`, etc.. in simple int value (milliseconds) and then formats it to represent in string format. You can create `new Date(2011, 100, 100)` and everythig will ok :)

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do what you do now and construct a new Date object and then afterwards check the value of myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth(), myDate.getDate(), to ensure that those values match the input values. Keep in mind that getMonth() and getDate() are 0 indexed, so January is month 0 and December is month 11.

Here's an example:

```
function isValidDate(year, month, day) {
    var d = new Date(year, month, day);

    return d.getFullYear() === year && d.getMonth() === month && d.getDate() === day;
}

console.log(isValidDate(2011,5,31));
console.log(isValidDate(2011,5,30));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question question however to help me and other after me, here is a php checkdate solution from the following webpage:

https://locutus.io/php/datetime/checkdate/

```
function checkdate (m, d, y) {
    return m > 0 && m < 13 && y > 0 && y < 32768 && d > 0 && d <= (new Date(y, m, 0))
    .getDate()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this the right way to do it:

```js
function isValidDate(year, month, day) {
  var d = new Date(year, month, day)
  if (month == 12) {
    year = parseInt(year) * 1 + 1 * 1
    month = 0
  }
  day = parseInt(day)
  month = parseInt(month)
  year = parseInt(year)
  if (month === 2 && day > 29) {
    return false
  }
  return (
    d.getFullYear() === year && d.getMonth() === month && d.getDate() === day
  )
}
```

Comment: Ehm, this was already answered over half a year ago! Thanks anyways.