# Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date

Tags: javascript, date

i am trying to convert a string in the format dd-mm-yyyy into a date object in JavaScript using the following:

```
 var from = $("#datepicker").val();
 var to = $("#datepickertwo").val();
 var f = new Date(from);
 var t = new Date(to);
```

`("#datepicker").val()` contains a date in the format dd-mm-yyyy. 
When I do the following, I get "Invalid Date":

```
alert(f);
```

Is this because of the '-' symbol? How can I overcome this?

Comment: Does this happen with all dates or one in particular?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

**Split on "-"**

Parse the string into the parts you need:

```
var from = $("#datepicker").val().split("-")
var f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0])
```

**Use regex**

```
var date = new Date("15-05-2018".replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"))
```

**Why not use regex?**

Because you know you'll be working on a string made up of three parts, separated by hyphens.

However, if you were looking for that same string within another string, regex would be the way to go.

**Reuse**

Because you're doing this more than once in your sample code, and maybe elsewhere in your code base, wrap it up in a function:

```
function toDate(dateStr) {
  var parts = dateStr.split("-")
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0])
}
```

Using as:

```
var from = $("#datepicker").val()
var to = $("#datepickertwo").val()
var f = toDate(from)
var t = toDate(to)
```

Or if you don't mind jQuery in your function:

```
function toDate(selector) {
  var from = $(selector).val().split("-")
  return new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0])
}
```

Using as:

```
var f = toDate("#datepicker")
var t = toDate("#datepickertwo")
```

**Modern JavaScript**

If you're able to use more modern JS, array destructuring is a nice touch also:

```
const toDate = (dateStr) => {
  const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split("-")
  return new Date(year, month - 1, day)
}
```

Comment: beat me to it...but I still use DateJs.  This isn't exactly correct due to a fence post error.  the month is 0-11 so you need to subtract 1. f = new Date(from[2], from[1]-1, from[0]);

Comment: Selected answer with a bug that produces wrong dates. Awesome!

Comment: Cheers @kasdega - Edited it... a while ago!

Comment: @AdrianLynch How to convert "Month dd, yyyy" into "MM/dd/yyyy" in javascript?

Comment: @AdrianLynch  I've date in “Month dd, yyyy” formate only. Now, I've to convert it into “MM/dd/yyyy". Please suggest me.

Comment: Doesn't it need to convert day, month and year to integer ?

Comment: Another example: `var date = new Date("11/04/1978".replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));`. NOTE: Using JavaScript Short Dates. Short dates are written with an "MM/DD/YYYY" syntax ( https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp ).

Comment: When I use Modern Javascript: `toDate(dateStr)` throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: toDate is not a function`. After I change the name to `toDateTest(dateStr)` it works fine. Any ideas @AdrianLynch?

Comment: A good answer except for the "use regex" example. `new Date("05-15-2018")` produces an invalid date in Safari and Firefox at least. Suggesting converting one unsupported format to another unsupported format for parsing by the built–in parser is fraught (as demonstrated). :-)

Answer (score 139):

regular expression example:

```
new Date( "13-01-2011".replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3") );
```

Comment: A revision that also takes `/` is delimiter and a year made of 2 digits (or any count bigger than 1): `replace( /(\d{2})[-/](\d{2})[-/](\d+)/, "$2/$1/$3")`

Comment: Why should this be the selected answer @AdemirNuno? Why use RegEx for a string in a known format? You're not looking for a pattern, you know the first number is the day, the second the month and the third the year. RegEx is the wrong tool for the job in this case.

Comment: A revision that takes non-digit delimiters, dates without leading zeroes and 2 or 4 digit years:
`new Date( "23. 2. 15".replace( /(\d+)[^d]+(\d+)[^d]+(\d+)/, "$2/$1/$3") );`
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: it's so  practice guy, thanks. my date format it comes with time, so i recode it as : 'new Date( "13-01-2011".replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\w)/, "$2/$1/$3") );'

is it right?

Comment: @NeerajSingh How to convert "Month dd, yyyy" into "MM/dd/yyyy" in javascript?

Comment: @dilipkumar1007: Please find your answer demo: https://jsfiddle.net/neerajsinghsonu/qhxgbuer/

Comment: A revision that also takes / is separator and a year made of 2 digits `replace(/(\d{2})[-,/](\d{2})[-,/](\d+)/, "$2/$1/$3")`

Answer (score 17):

Another possibility:

```
var from = "10-11-2011"; 
var numbers = from.match(/\d+/g); 
var date = new Date(numbers[2], numbers[0]-1, numbers[1]);
```

Match the digits and reorder them

Comment: Also the original question specified "dd-mm-yyyy", not "mm-dd-yyyy", so it's still wrong (but only just).

Comment: @epascarello How to convert "Month dd, yyyy" into "MM/dd/yyyy" in javascript?

Comment: `var date = new Date(numbers[2], numbers[1]-1, numbers[0]);`

Answer (score 11):

Using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) example:

```
var from = '11-04-2017' // OR $("#datepicker").val();
var milliseconds = moment(from, "DD-MM-YYYY").format('x');
var f = new Date(milliseconds)
```

Comment: moment(from, "DD-MM-YYYY").toDate()

Answer (score 9):

Use this format: `myDate = new Date('2011-01-03'); // Mon Jan 03 2011 00:00:00`

Comment: Where did you get that `parseDate` function from? Is that a native javascript function?

Comment: sorry how do I implement this? also I need the format as dd-mm-yy

Comment: parseDate is a native JS function. For more info see: http://www.xaprb.com/articles/javascript-date-parsing-demo.html

Comment: @user559142 - you're confusing what JavaScript needs to make a date object out of a string INPUT and how you want the OUTPUT of your date to look like as a string. They're two different beasts.

Comment: @Diodeus...really it is native? how come ff and chrome throw errors?

Comment: No, you're right. I've got too many JS frameworks in my head.

Comment: @Diodeus even with the last edit this doesn't quite work for me (with Chrome at least). It sets the date to `'2011-01-03'` and the UTC time to `00:00:00`. So if the user's time zone is less than UTC, it will actually be the day before.

Comment: @Diodeus :  how to convert myDate = '20/06/17' into '20/6/2017 00:00:00' format

Answer (score 6):

```
var from = $("#datepicker").val(); 
var f = $.datepicker.parseDate("d-m-Y", from);
```

Comment: Were are you getting Date.parseDate?

Comment: @kasdega Sorry, I was thinking of $.datepicker.parseDate, fixed it now :)

Comment: You should use `$.datepicker.parseDate("dd-mm-yy", from);` to properly parse a date like `24-01-2017`, chek datepicker documentation at https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer kinda has a bug

```
var from = $("#datepicker").val().split("-")
var f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0])
```

Consider if the datepicker contains "77-78-7980" which is obviously not a valid date. This would result in:

```
var f = new Date(7980, 77, 77);
=> Date 7986-08-15T22:00:00.000Z
```

Which is probably not the desired result.

The reason for this is explained on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) site:

> Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g. `new Date(2013, 13, 1)` is equivalent to `new Date(2014, 1, 1)`.

---

A better way to solve the problem is:

```
const stringToDate = function(dateString) {
  const [dd, mm, yyyy] = dateString.split("-");
  return new Date(`${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`);
};

console.log(stringToDate('04-04-2019'));
// Date 2019-04-04T00:00:00.000Z

console.log(stringToDate('77-78-7980'));
// Invalid Date
```

This gives you the possibility to handle invalid input.

For example:

```
const date = stringToDate("77-78-7980");

if (date === "Invalid Date" || isNaN(date)) {
  console.log("It's all gone bad");
} else {
  // Do something with your valid date here
}
```

Comment: The "better way" parses the values as UTC, which is likely unexpected. It's pretty simple to validate the values by including a check, e.g. [*Check date in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800253/check-date-in-javascript). ;-)

Comment: Fair point. However, the accepted answer for that question also doesn't take time zones into account. Consequently (for me in my time zone) it considers `new Date(2011,5,29)` to be an invalid date. See here: [Is the Javascript date object always one day off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/is-the-javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off)

Answer (score 3):

You can also write a date inside the parentheses of the `Date()` object, like these:

```
new Date("Month dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss")
new Date("Month dd, yyyy")
new Date(yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss)
new Date(yyyy,mm,dd)
new Date(milliseconds)
```

Comment: @AmitSengar How to convert "Month dd, yyyy" into "MM/dd/yyyy" in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

In my case

```
new Date("20151102034013".replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6"))
```

Result: Mon Nov 02 2015 04:40:13 GMT+0100 (CET)
then I use .getTime() to work with milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

```js
let dateString  = '13-02-2021' //date string in dd-mm-yyyy format

let dateArray = dateString.split("-");
//dateArray[2] equals to 2021
//dateArray[1] equals to 02
//dateArray[0] equals to 13

// using template literals below

let dateObj = new Date(`${dateArray[2]}-${dateArray[1]}-${dateArray[0]}`);

// dateObj equals to Sat Feb 13 2021 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

//I'm from India so its showing GMT+0530
```

P.S : Always refer docs for basics, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) or [DevDocs](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/date/date)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an external library to help you out.

http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/source.html

```
getDateFromFormat(val,format);
```

Also see this: [Parse DateTime string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-date-string-in-javascript)

Comment: how to convert myDate = '20/06/17' into '20/6/2017 00:00:00' format in javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) for all those petty date related issues.. You could solve this by parseDate function too

Answer (score 1):

You can just:

```
var f = new Date(from.split('-').reverse().join('/'));
```

Comment: This converts 2023-11-17 to 17/11/2023 which is an ivalid date. It should be 11/17/2023 to be an correct date. Day and Month is twissted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regexp.

```
var result = /^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/.exec($("#datepicker").val());
if (result) {
    from = new Date(
        parseInt(result[3], 10), 
        parseInt(result[2], 10) - 1, 
        parseInt(result[1], 10)
    );
}
```

Comment: Produces the wrong month! Months start at zero, not one. So if you did Jan, yours would say Feb.

Comment: @epascarello - Forgot how lame the Date API is.

Comment: @ChaosPandion : how to convert myDate = '20/06/17' into '20/6/2017 00:00:00' format in javascript ?

Answer (score -2):

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

simple as that, just pass your date to js Date Object

Comment: Do you mean passing the date string inside the Date constructor like, `new Date('30/12/2018').toLocaleDateString()`?? That returns **Invalid Date**

Comment: What happened with the user date?