# jQuery datepicker sending a date one day ahead to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, server

In the jQuery datepicker, I select a date(e.g. **04/05/2015**) and click submit.
When I reload the form with getting the values from server, it shows a date ahead by one day (**05/05/2015**). I want to get the same date back from server which I selected using datepicker.

I searched a little and found `jquery` uses client side date.
How to make it use server side date?

This is just a fragment of code.

```
function loadProductDataFromBrowser(currentStoreName) {
    $("#datepickerExpiresOn").datepicker({ appendText: "(yyyymmdd)", altFormat: "yymmdd", dateFormat: "yymmdd" });
}

function loadProductFromServerData(data, currentStoreName){
    document.getElementById('datepickerExpiresOn').value = data.expiresOn;
    $("#datepickerExpiresOn").datepicker({ appendText: "(yyyymmdd)", altFormat: "yymmdd", dateFormat: "yymmdd" });
}
```

Comment: Check this out. May be you are facing the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509360/datepicker-date-off-by-one-day

Comment: No, I saw this answer but it didn't help.

Comment: @PragyaSharma, This site doesn't work like u think! I didn't downvoted ur Q, just edited it to make more readable!

Comment: For me it seems like server-side problem.  Can you make sure the date is properly getting stored and also check the date returned from the server

Comment: I dont have access to the server. When I alert the value returned from server, it gives the date one day ahead.