# Strange bug with date input and angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date

I'm working on angular based app and i have a really strange bug..
When i use:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date">
```

the `$scope.date` has one day delay...

When I try to run the attachment code it prints the `date` which I have selected but with one day delay :(
 What can I do?!

Thank you :)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app">
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="date" ng-model="date">
    {{ date }}
      
    </body>
  </body>
```

Comment: Have you looked into which timezone(s) is/are being used? A difference of -1 or more hours can cause the previous date to be displayed.

Comment: it works fine for me, its showing same date what i select from calendar. i think its timezone problem for you.

Comment: I know that it's works fine here! The bug is in my project...

Comment: How can i check this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [datepicker date off by one day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509360/datepicker-date-off-by-one-day)

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine. The result is displaying in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: I know that the code works fine here... But it's not works fine on my project :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it is similar this issue : [Jquery Datepicker off by one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509360/datepicker-date-off-by-one-day)

I have solved by using momentjs library. It provides lots of time-zone methods.

```
moment.utc([year, month, day])._d
```

Comment: I'll try this later... But i'm sure that there is a solution without using any library...

Comment: @Yehuda you are right. Actually there is no need any library but momentjs is really great tool.