# HTML5: hour from "Date()" object in <input type='time'>

Tags: javascript, html, date, dom, input

I have some HTML file with 2 objects:

```
<input type='date' id = 'datepicker1'>
<input type='time' id = 'timepicker1'>
```

I use the `.valueAsDate` attribute in order to set the date and time to be the current ones:

```
document.getElementById("datepicker1").valueAsDate = new Date();
document.getElementById("timepicker1").valueAsDate = new Date();
```

While the **date picker** shows today's date perfectly (March 16, 2016), the time picker shows the time 2 hours ago (**compared to the computer time**).
For example, if I load the HTML page in **18:26:32**, the time picker will instead show **16:26:32**.

It has the same behavior when I use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date()`

Any idea how to solve it?

**EDIT:**

***Here is the solution, it works amazingly*** (Thanks to @LGSon's):
 (from  link here: [Javascript Date() give wrong date off by one hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469269/javascript-date-give-wrong-date-off-by-one-hour)):

```
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("datepicker1").valueAsDate = d.getTime() - d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
```

Comment: I'll make it more clear also in the question itself - it shows 2 hours ago comparing to the time of the computer

Comment: You can get the date as UTC instead and that should return the correct time...

Comment: note: since there is no timezone setting for the input, the time input seems to default to GMT when setting from a Date object: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html . The time is actually correct, it's just for another timezone. set with a string to align user expectations.

Comment: It seems that `Date.now()` does not return the current local time, but the UTC time. How can I convert it to the local time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469269/javascript-date-give-wrong-date-off-by-one-hour

Comment: Date.now() is the local time which is the same as UTC. all the clocks are the same. Time matters _where_ you are asking, not just _when_ you are asking. That said, `new Date().toLocaleString()`, `new Date().toLocaleDateString()`, and `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` can be used, but DON'T rely on a specific format of those strings, they can vary among browsers and local settings.

Comment: @SomethingSomething I completely missed it was tagged java :) .. deleted it

Comment: a good way to get local date parts: `new Date( Date.now() - (1000*60*new Date().getTimezoneOffset())).toISOString().split(/[\WT]/);` ... yeah, it takes 3 Date calls, but it's still semi-simple... you can substitute another date for the `Date.now()` part to format a specific date instead of the current one.

Comment: @LGSon, your link solved my problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: @dandavis—the alternative is to create a date, then use *getHours*, *getMinutes* and *getSeconds*. Of course you can always add custom *getLocalTime* and *getUTCTime* methods that return formatted time strings. ;-)