# Conversion from timestamp to time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

My problem is that I am receiving a timestamp from another app.
When I convert the timestamp to time the time that gets returned is always wrong

This is the JavaScript code:

```
var time = new Date(timeStamp);
```

timeStamp = 1520934000461.
My app returns the time: Tue Mar 13 2018 10:40:00
and the actual time is one hour earlier.

I tested the timeStamp with online converters and the converting is right and the timeStamp that comes to my app is right.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be a problem about your client or server time config. Check your client's and server's timezone.

Otherwise, you can use this hacky solution  (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469269/javascript-date-give-wrong-date-off-by-one-hour))

`d = new Date(value) ;
d.setTime( d.getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );`