# date.getHours() returns different value for browser and mobile devices

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hell,

I am trying to work with dates in React Native and I am struggling to understand why it adds another 2 hours when I call date.getHours().

This is what I receive from backend: `2018-06-03T11:00:00`.

This is a final locale date with hours that I should present to the user, so I expect when I call `new Date('2018-06-03T11:00:00').getHours()` it should return `11`. And it works well in a browser without a problem, but when I use it in my React Native project on both platforms (iOS and Android) it returns for me `13` instead of `11`.

What am I missing? How to explicitly tell `Date` that it should not convert it again to date with different timezone?

Comment: This will probably solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469269/javascript-date-give-wrong-date-off-by-one-hour#comment52838280_32476132

Comment: Thanks, seems to fixed the issue for me. Yet I still don't get it why it works this way... :)