# Javascript date showing a different time by using New Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a following date time

```
'2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z'
```

when I am trying to use it

```
new Date('2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z')
```

it returns

```
Thu Aug 05 2021 18:08:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Date wise it is fine as it is in the given string, but about time it is  not returning the correct time

can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Both `2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z` and `Thu Aug 05 2021 18:08:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` represent the same moment in time, it's just that local time is represented with an offset to UTC

Comment: What is the actual problem that this is causing?

Comment: the question should be how to convert UTC date to IST

Comment: Same moment in different time zones. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: The "z" at the end of the timestamp indicates the initial time is in the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 0):

`'2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z'` is the UTC time format, where it is used regardless of any timezone.

But when you are displaying datetime, mostly you will need to display your local time, in this case is your India Standard Time (GMT+0530)

e.g. if you want to get hours, which you still can get both your local and the UTC hours:

```
const d = new Date('2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z')
d.getHours()
d.getUTCHours()
```

Comment: Here, what is happening , it is showing 1 hour ahead of current time

Comment: @ganeshk it depends on the string you put, so if you put correct string would work `'2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also display the UTC time with [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

```
const d = new Date('2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z')
const isoTime = d.toISOString()
//2021-08-05T12:38:27.163Z
```

For another input:

```
const d = new Date('2021-08-05 12:00 UTC')
const isoTime = d.toISOString()
//2021-08-05T12:00:00.000Z
```

If the string for new Date does not contain a UTC identifier, then the time is interpreted as local time. The UTC time is then usually different.

```
const d = new Date('2021-08-05 12:00')
const isoTime = d.toISOString()
//2021-08-05T10:00:00.000Z
```

(Local time zone Europe/berlin daylight saving time)

Comment: Why? This just gets back the original string that you parsed in the first place (almost)

Comment: @jspit , it is showing a 1 hour ahead from the current time

Comment: The timestamp determines with  + new Date('2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z') must return 1628167107163.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the local time back to UTC.

```js
var d = new Date('2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z');
var n = d.toUTCString();
console.log(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

`z` is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset
so `new Date('2021-08-05T12:38:27.163z')` will be displayed in your local timezone .
so if you want the same time appeating remove the `z`

```
new Date('2021-08-05T12:38:27.163')
```

Comment: Actually it works with the date but it shows 1 hour ahead time in local

Comment: Here, what is 163z?

Comment: 163 are milliseconds and z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset

Comment: Actually not sure why but it shows one hour ahead everytime ? what might be the reason ?

Comment: Clocks go back in winter by one hour.

Comment: see this to understand more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469269/javascript-date-give-wrong-date-off-by-one-hour