# Datepickers are not returning chosen dates

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Here's the problem with my **datepickers**.I tried three approaches which ultimately gave same wrong result.

**Input type date**:

```
 <input type="date" ng-model="d.e_date" class="date"/>
```

**Result:** returned 2016-03-31 on choosing 1 April 2016 and 2016-04-06 on choosing 7April 2016.(One Day Back)

**UI Bootstrap's datepicker and Jquery's datepicker:**

**Result:** they also gave same result for format "yyyy/MM/dd".while i used them with format "MM/yyyy" and they returned 12/2013 on choosing January 2014 and 11/2015 on choosing December 2015.

**Conclusion:** As far as i could understand,it is somehow subtracting one point.like one day back in full date format and one month back in month's format.

[datepicker date off by one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509360/datepicker-date-off-by-one-day)

This is the link i checked and also tried replacing "-" with "/" as mentioned in above post but no luck.

### Update:

I am actually getting this date value in Angular controller and sending it to server.In Controller date is returned in **"Thu Apr 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0500"** on choosing 1st april 2010 while when its is submitted to service as

```
console.log($scope.s_month);// returns this Thu Apr 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0500

Restangular.all("s_session/create").post({s_month:$scope.s_month}).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });//returns '2010-03-31T19:00:00.000Z' according to browser's network tab.
```

Comment: This problem is repeatable? Can we see a an example of your code?