# Date input showing value one day prior

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

The date on the selector (ngx-bootstrap datepicker) is showing one day older date.

If the date value is

> 2019-04-26T18:30:00

The datepicker shows it as 04/25/2019.
For the datepicker input I doing the following thing-

```
this.dateAdded = new Date(this.user.dateAdded).toLocaleDateString();
```

I am at GMT+5:30 so even adjusting for timezone I don't understand why it is going one day beind.

Comment: Identify what is the difference of time and add it up on reaching the server.. Here in your case 5hr 30 Mins should be added to the date value in all cases

Comment: @Ajith that's a pretty hacky solution, it's better to identify and fix the source of the issue.

Comment: Hey, the DateTime value I have written is the one I am receiving from server.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, if you add console.logs around that line in the code and check the values of `this.user.dateAdded` and the result value of `this.dateAdded` after the line executes, does it work as intended?

Comment: console.log(this.user.dateAdded) =2019-04-26T18:30:00; console.log(this.user.dateAdded.toLocaleDateString() = 04/26/2019. However on the form the date appears as 04/25/2019

Comment: Checkout this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509360/datepicker-date-off-by-one-day

Comment: This one too https://stackoverflow.com/a/31732581/5028715

Comment: Seems like an on-going issue regarding to ngx-bootstrap datepicker https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3609

Answer (score 1):

After spending the better part of the day and learning about the complexities that come with displaying date in Javascript the answer to this specific question is a bit of an anticlimax.
The version of ngx-bootstrap I was using (5.2) has some bugs with the datepicker.
Use the 5.1 version so as to not have the issue with the date.
It seems like ToLocaleDateString which only gives the date component if adjusted for timezone by bsDatePicker (at midnight) gives the previous day.

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3609
Reference for github issue regarding the same.

Comment: We encountered the same problem with ngx-bootstrap 5.2 on a legacy project, and determined that 5.3.2 has the datepicker timezone issue fixed, for anyone who would prefer to move a minor version forward rather than backward.