# date-range picker picks date of the day before

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using angular daterange picker to pick one date and here is how my html looks like:

```
<input date-range-picker ng-model="model" options="{singleDatePicker: true}"
       class="form-control date-picker" type="text"/>
```

Now when I select a date when the calender pops up, it selects the date apparently but when it is sent to backend, it is actually the date of one day before. i.e, If I select `28-02-2020` it will send `27-02-2020`. Also, I just want the datepicker to send just the date, currently it sends it something like this:

```
2020-02-27T19:00:00.000Z
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help?

Comment: Seems like a timezone issue. Have you checked the options/timezone settings?

Comment: There isn't a built-in date-range-picker in AngularJS. Can you indicate which one you are using ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41125840/6885735

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/is-the-javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off/31732581#31732581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your timezone to date by using the following way,

```
var d = new Date('yourDate');
d.setMinutes( d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset() );

'd' should be the correct date
```

**Or** 
You can also check by simply doing like `'Your Date'.toISOString()`

Comment: I still get the date of one day older. The problem is still there. I selected 2020-03-12 and it sends 2020-03-11.

Comment: Can you provide your code in stackblitz so that it would be more easy to debug. @Saani

Answer (score 4):

With AngularJS, date pickers need to set the `ng-model-options` timezone to UTC:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="pickedDate" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'utc'}">
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-model-options Directive API Reference - Specifying Timezones](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#specifying-timezones)

### The DEMO

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <input type="date" ng-model="pickedDate" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'utc'}">
    <br>
    pickedDate={{pickedDate}}
</body>
```