# Creating date with 31 as day gives 30 in output

Tags: javascript, date

I'm creating dates from strings with the format 'yyyy-MM-dd' but they're always created on the previous day for some reason. If I set the date as '2012-10-31' the Date object with actually be 30 of October and not 31. For example, this:

```
var d1=new Date('2012-10-31');
```

Will output this:

```
Tue Oct 30 2012 19:30:00 GMT-0430 (Venezuela Standard Time)
```

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: what is your UTC offset?

Comment: How can I compensate then? To get the time in my actual timezone?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no further parameters, Date() create your time-stamp with GMT+0000.

Converting your date to string with no further parameters either, it will use the localised notation.
If you want to create a date matching your time-zone, do:

```
var d1=new Date('2012-10-31 GMT-0430');
//That's what you should get
//"Wed Oct 31 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0430"
```

---

Using this date now, you can convert the local time to the time of other timezones if you execute d1.toString() in a browser with a different timezone:

```
d1.toString();
//That's what I get
//"Wed Oct 31 2012 05:30:00 GMT+0100"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var d1=new Date(2012, 10-1, 31, 0, 0 ,0);
document.write(d1);
```

which produces

```
Wed Oct 31 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

the key is to remove the quotes and manually set the time. Also note that 'month' is zero based and so for readability I subtract one from it

Comment: I see the problem now, since the date isn't getting created with any time information is just takes it as GMT 0000 and rolls it back to my timezone.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because dates are *converted to a string* based on your local time zone.

The date variable actually contains October 31st 0:00 UTC. When you convert it to string, it is converted using your own time-zone, which is 4:30 hours behind UTC.