# Initializing javascript Date with ISO 8601 date string produces date value -1 day

Tags: javascript, datetime, iso

```
var date = new Date('2013-04-15');
console.log(date);
```

Outputs:

```
Sun Apr 14 2013 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Which is -1 Day, why does Date have this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

These two timestamps represent the same time:

```
Sun Apr 14 2013 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
Mon Apr 15 2013 00:00:00 UTC
```

You're getting the first, but expecting the second. The date constructor appears to take a time in UTC.

If you do:

```
var date = new Date('2013-04-15 EDT');
console.log(date);
```

Then you'll probably get the intended result

---

**Edit:** [This behavior is bizarre](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14976646/102441). This code works as you intend it to:

```
var date = new Date('Apr 15 2013');
console.log(date);

Mon Apr 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT+XYZ
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I set dates it assumes the UTC timezone? Is there anyway to set dates in the current time zone of the browser?

Comment: Any way to know the browsers timezone?

Comment: @CaseyFlynn: What are you trying to get here? Are you looking for the timestamp representing the start of the day for the timezone of the viewer looking at the page?

Comment: I have some ISO formatted dates, and my users are in different timezones. I want to show which dates are today/upcoming or past in two groups for the user in their given timezone.

Comment: @Casey: As far as I can tell, ISO formatted dates are defined to always represent UTC. Therefore, the `Date` constructor is parsing them correctly

Comment: Hmm okay, maybe I should write some kind of regex parser to create a date object in an alternate format that parses for the user's locale.

Comment: @CaseyFlynn: Why are you not storing a UTC date in the first place?

Comment: not my application. Something I'm working on for someone else and whoever came before me did it this way.

Comment: @CaseyFlynn: So if I travel to another timezone, the application starts giving me incorrect times? If you're storing local times, then you need to store the time zone associated with them. Getting that from the users browser is a bad idea.

Comment: no the application stores dates w/ corresponding time zones instead of UTC/GMT datetimes. Not ideal

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the timezone to get the output you're looking for.

An example here: [Javascript date object always one day off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off)

Answer (score 0):

Because `new Date()` is using UTC time, the `toString()` use your current timezone.

If you want to print the UTC time, you should use

```
var date = new Date('2013-04-15');
console.log(date.toUTCString());
```