# Why does javascript interpret these identical dates differently

Tags: javascript, date

What's going on here:

```
> new Date('Apr 15 2013');
Mon Apr 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
> new Date('04/15/2013');
Mon Apr 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
> new Date('2013-04-15');
Mon Apr 15 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Obviously, one is being interpreted as UTC time, while the other two are being interpreted as local time. What causes the difference in parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.2):

> The String may be interpreted as a **local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String**. The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format ([15.9.1.15](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15)). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.

Of all the formats you provided, only `'2013-04-15'` is officially supported, so the others seem to fall back to implementation-dependent behavior.

Comment: The section you quoted from MDN is likely detailing the Gecko implementation behaviour (since as the spec shows, this situation is left up to the implementation).

Comment: @Eric: It could be either an implementation detail for Firefox or an unofficial, but widely supported feature. Chrome seems to behave the same way, so it might be the latter.

Comment: +1. This graphically highlights the dangers of trying to parse arbitrary date strings. The same caveats apply in other languages too (the quirks in php's `strtotime()` have to be seen to be believed). The best advice is always to accept dates either in a fixed known format, preferably `yyyy-mm-dd`, or simply to always use an integer timestamp. Anything else is playing with fire. This applies even more so when sending data between systems. And user input on a form should be with a calendar control rather than free-type.

Answer (score 2):

The `Date` constructor delegates to [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), and it appears that `Date.parse` has two variants:

> Given a string representing a time, parse returns the time value. It
>   accepts the **RFC2822 / IETF date syntax (RFC2822 Section 3.3)**, e.g.
>   "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT". It understands the continental US
>   time-zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time-zone offset,
>   for example, "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT+0430" (4 hours, 30 minutes
>   east of the Greenwich meridian). **If you do not specify a time zone,
>   the local time zone is assumed**. GMT and UTC are considered equivalent.
>
> Alternatively, the date/time string may be in
>   **ISO 8601 format**. Starting with JavaScript 1.8.5 (Firefox 4), a subset
>   of ISO 8601 is supported. For example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or
>   "2011-10-10T14:48:00 (date and time) can be passed and parsed.

Clearly, these behave differently with respect to local timezones

---

**Edit:** Looks like this is [implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976646/why-does-javascript-interpret-these-identical-dates-differently/14976903#comment21030278_14976903)

Answer (score 2):

Your third example is the only one that is actually explained by the spec. When you call the `Date` constructor with a single argument, [this is what happens](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.3.2) (where `v` is the string passed to the constructor):

> Parse `v` as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the `parse` method (15.9.4.2); let `V` be the time value for this date.

The [`parse` method](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.2) will attempt to parse the string (emphasis added):

> **The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String**. The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15).
>
> **If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats**.

And the "[Date Time String Format](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15)" is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, and also defines a shorter version of the form `YYYY-MM-DD`, which is what you use in your third example.

For the other examples, the parse will fail and the behaviour is implementation-defined.