# Javascript Date Gives me EDT but I want EST

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

I am receiving a MySQL Timestamp in UTC and trying to covert it to the client's local timezone. However, When i do this I get the wrong time zone.

Ive formatted my `DateTime` String to be: `var utcTime = 2014-05-15T13:00:00Z`

However when after my conversion my dateObject is: `Date {Thu May 15 2014 09:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)}`. However, I want my Timezone to be GMT -0500 (EST).

I've searched online and saw there is a way to do this by appending "UTC" to a MYSQL formatted Timestamp.. However, this method does not work in all browsers.

If anyone has any insight on converting timezones i would appreciate it.

Comment: EST ends in March, if yoy want GMT -05 00 for May 15 you need Central Daylight Time

Comment: @kennebec The Date portion of the time stamp is irrelevant to me... My true objective is really converting the time to reflect a users local time zone... I used an fake date so i could convert it.

Answer (score 1):

The D in EDT stands for Daylight and the S in EST stands for Standard. EDT should be used during Summer in the U.S. and EST in the Winter ([list of countries here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html)). Is it possible that GMT -4 (EDT) is actually the right local time? If it would be more towards winter it would switch automatically to GMT -5 (EST). The client timezone together with daylight savings is handled automatically by Javascript.

For example, the default string representation of a certain date in Javascript should correctly choose between Standard time and Daylight Savings time based on the date object itself and the machine timezone:

```
var date = new Date(millisSinceUnixEpoch);
alert(date.toDateString() + ' ' + date.toTimeString());
```

Note: there's room for a lot of assumption though. E.g. not sure exactly how your 'conversion to local timezone' code looks like

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something similar to this. This MSDN article may explain it.

**Handling daylight saving time using JavaScript**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj863688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> In Windows Internet Explorer 9 and previous versions of Windows
>   Internet Explorer, dates are customized by applying the ECMAScript
>   specification's rules for storing daylight saving time adjusted times
>   internally. To improve accuracy, especially with dates in the past
>   (historical dates), Internet Explorer 10 relies on the system's rules
>   for storing daylight saving time adjusted times. This topic contains
>   the following sections: