# React Javascript Subtract One Day

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this prop `this.props.SearchDate` coming in as a format like this `2016-03-31` (yyyy-MM-DD)

If I do

```
let date = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1)).toISOString().substring(0,10);
console.log(date)
```

I get the correct yesterday date, but if I do

```
let date = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date(this.props.SearchDate).getDate() - 1)).toISOString().substring(0,10);
console.log(date)
```

I get `2019-04-29`

If I remove -1, then it gets the date 30. Though actually since current date there is 31 then -1 should make day before 30.

All I need from date is to give it yyyy-mm-dd some date, and get exactly 1 date before than that. Can anyone see the problem here?
This seem to be explained here: [Why does js subtract a day from a Date object with a certain format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344408/why-does-js-subtract-a-day-from-a-date-object-with-a-certain-format)

I will share the solution to my problem.

Comment: converting to unix time and subtracting a day's worth of milliseconds might be easier `new Date(new Date('2016-03-31').valueOf() - 86400000)`

Comment: If you're doing a lot of date manipulation, you should consider using a library dedicated to dates, like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/). Dealing with dates and time zones is hard work.

Comment: Note that `toISOString` returns the date and time in UTC, which is likely different from your local time zone. You need to adjust for that difference if you want to use `toISOString`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does js subtract a day from a Date object with a certain format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344408/why-does-js-subtract-a-day-from-a-date-object-with-a-certain-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Daniel Lizik's answer on this did the job for me along with time zone set.

```
new Date(new Date('2016-03-31').valueOf() - 86400000)
```