# Why is getting the `MMMM` format on the first day of the month returning the previous month using moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why is getting the `MMMM` format on the first day of the month returning the previous month, but returning the correct month starting with the second day of the month, using this format `2020-08-01T00:00:00Z`? Does it have to do with the timezone offset? Example case below:

With the first day of the month:

```js
start = "2020-08-01T00:00:00Z";
month = moment(start).format("MMMM");
console.log(month) // <- July
```

With the second day of the month:

```js
start = "2020-08-02T00:00:00Z";
month = moment(start).format("MMMM");
console.log(month) // <- August
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does js subtract a day from a Date object with a certain format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344408/why-does-js-subtract-a-day-from-a-date-object-with-a-certain-format)

Comment: @HereticMonkey this is helpful, but the answer accepted below answers this particular question related to moment js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is because Moment objects are, by default, [created](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/) in the local timezone. So if your local timezone is UTC minus anything and you create a `moment` with a midnight UTC time string, you will get the last day of the previous month.

To prevent this you can [use](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) `utc()`, `parseZone()`, a string that does not include the time, or you can specify the timezone using the `moment-timezone` package:

```js
start = "2020-08-01T00:00:00Z";
month = moment(start).format("MMMM");
monthUTC = moment(start).utc().format("MMMM"); // or moment.utc(start).format("MMMM");
monthPZ = moment.parseZone(start).format("MMMM");
monthNoTime = moment("2020-08-01").format("MMMM");

// Note: Requires separate moment-timezone package
monthLA = moment(start).tz('America/Los_Angeles').format("MMMM");
monthSYD = moment(start).tz('Australia/Sydney').format("MMMM");

console.log("Default: ", month);
console.log("UTC: ", monthUTC);
console.log("parseZone: ", monthPZ);
console.log("No time: ", monthNoTime);
console.log("LA: ", monthLA);
console.log("Sydney: ", monthSYD);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```