# Getting Wrong Value of Input Type "Month"

Tags: jquery, css, forms, input

I'm trying to get the value of the input type "month" - 2 digit month and 2 digit year.

**PROBLEM**
Format correct, but returns wrong date.

**CODE**

```js
$("#cardExpireDate").change(function() {
 var expireDate = new Date ( $(this).val() );
  //var expireDay = expireDate.getDate();
  var expireMonth = expireDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var expireYear = parseInt(expireDate.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2), 10);
 var expireDateMMYY = ([expireMonth, expireYear]).join('/');
  //alert([expireMonth, expireYear].join('/'));
 $("#summaryCardExpireDate").val( expireDateMMYY );
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800);
.container {width:400px; margin:0 auto;}
label {float:left; margin:10px 0; vertical-align:middle; line-height:30px;}
input {width:200px; height:30px; margin:10px; 0; vertical-align:middle; font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif; font-size:15px; border:0; outline:0;}
#cardExpireDate {border:1px solid #999;}
#summaryCardExpireDate {border:0; border-bottom:1px solid #999;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="formField">
    <input type="month" id="cardExpireDate" name="card_expire_date" placeholder="Expiration..." title="Card Expire Date" required="">
    <label class="" for="cardExpireDate">Expiration Date:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="summaryCardExpireDate">
    <label class="" for="summaryCardExpireDate">Returned Value:
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CODEPEN**
http://codepen.io/zuhloobie/pen/ggWdLj

Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE**
This is what I see on Google Chrome: Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64 bit):
[image]

Comment: I could not understand what's the problem?

Comment: Me too, the mm/yy format looks fine, and the months match up to the numbers from what I could see.

Comment: Choosing January 2017 returns "12/16" - should be "01/17"

Comment: Choosing June 2017 returns "5/17" - should be "05/17"

Comment: I am reading this page using Google Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) and when choosing January 2017 it returns `1/17` in the second input field. @chris

Comment: I'm using Goggle Chrome: Version 55.0.2883.87 m on 64 bit as well - but when I choose Jan 2017, it returns 12/16. I'm horribly confused now.

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot of what I see....

Comment: If you run `var rn = new Date(); rn.toUTCString()` in your browser console what is returned?

Comment: For me, the value returned from the new Date() in Chrome is wrong in my browser console log. However, it is correct in the codepen console log running on the stack overflow site.

Comment: In that case, I think the local settings of your OS may take a rule in this issue! In my case it is Windows 10 with regional seetings English US

Comment: @BrettDeWoody - "Sun, 22 Jan 2017 22:42:49 GMT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging date object shows that date is `Sun Jan 01 2017 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))`. It is **right the start of a month**. Take a look at your localization, you must have not a UTC time. I would fix the issue just by adding 1 day to a date.

```
var expireDate = new Date ( $(this).val() );
expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
```

Looks like you are in western hemisphere of Earth. This will probably make it clear, why creating `Date` object is so sensible: [Javascript date object always one day off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this worked. Curious why someone downvoted it?

Answer (score 1):

If you went to have month value in two digits you have to change **var expireMonth**:

from : var expireMonth = expireDate.getMonth() + 1;

to : var expireMonth=('0'+(expireDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);

It works fine :)

Comment: Don't add multiple answers please. If your first one is wrong, then edit it or delete it.