# Formatting UTC date-time's partial seconds

Tags: java, string, datetime, jodatime, utc

After parsing JSON UTC date-time data from a server, I was presented with

```
2017-03-27 16:27:45.567
```

... is there any way to format this without using tedious amount of String manipulation so that the seconds part is rounded up to 46 prior to passing it in as a DateTimeFormat pattern of say, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"?

Comment: Which time library are you using?

Comment: @shmosel Joda-time!

Comment: It can be done directly while parsing the json into object. What is your json lib jackson or gson? Also, show the java bean class. Are you using any restful lib?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just include `.SSS` in the format pattern?  You can round later.

Answer (score 1):

You can round the second up like this:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        .withZoneUTC()
        .parseDateTime("2017-03-27 16:27:45.567")
        .secondOfMinute()
        .roundCeilingCopy();

System.out.println(dateTime);
// 2017-03-27T16:27:46.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at (and could you use) the [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) library?  I had issues with reading various date formats from the server and making sense of them in JavaScript code (which led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off)).  Since then, I've used MomentJS and working with dates/times in JavaScript has been much easier.

Here is an example:

```
<script>
    try
    {
        var myDateString = "2017-03-27 16:27:45.567";
        var d = moment(myDateString);

        var result = d.format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
        alert("Simple Format: " + result);

        // If we have millliseconds, increment to the next second so that 
        // we can then get its 'floor' by using the startOf() function.
        if(d.millisecond() > 0)
            d = d.add(1, 'second');

        result = d.startOf('second').format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
        alert("Rounded Format: " + result);
    }
    catch(er)
    {
        console.log(er);
    }
</script>
```

But of course, you'll probably want to wrap this logic into a function.

Comment: The question wasn't about JavaScript.