# Date is one day off when referenced inside nodejs application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, date, typescript

Ok so this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off/31732581#31732581) however the solutions given don't seem to resolve my issue.

I have the following:[image]

When I click save I refer to the these fields and create a date as shown here:

```
this.profile.date_of_birth = new Date(this.editProfileForm.value['year'], this.editProfileForm.value['month'], this.editProfileForm.value['day']);
```

Which when logged to the console reads:

> Fri Dec 23 1988 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)

I then make a call to my `nodejs` application which is running on `http://localhost:3005`, which takes the data and saves it to `mongodb`, before the save happens I log the value of date_of_birth as shown here:

```
api.put('/update', authenticate, (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body.date_of_birth);

    // Save properties

});
```

however this logs:

> 1988-12-22T13:00:00.000Z

which is a day off....

I'm not doing any formatting before creating a new date when the user presses save, so I'm unsure into why when it leaves the front end application, and gets to the backend application the date is displayed incorrect....

The actual call to the `nodejs` application is here:

```
saveProfile(profileId: string, token: string, profile: Profile): Observable<any> {

        var body = {
            "id": profile.id,
            "date_of_birth": profile.date_of_birth,
        }


        return this.http.put(UPDATE_EDIT_PROFILE, body, {
            headers: this.setHeaders(token)
        }).map((res: any) => res.json());

    }
```

Can anyone recommend what could possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fri Dec 23 1988 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)` is date with the current timezone. and your server seems using `UTC` according to `1988-12-22T13:00:00.000Z`.

you can use **[Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)** to create a Date Object with `standart timezone of UTC` which keeps same to your server.

```js
var year = 1988;
var month = 12;
var day = 23;
console.log(new Date(year, month - 1, day));
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day)));
```