# Date from input type="date"to new Date is incorrect date output

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `input="date"` of which i am trying to pull the day, month, and year individually and it seems to be off by a day or so. For example if i Put in 01/01/1900 it seems to be spitting back out 1899 11 31. So for a basic example I have -

```js
function clickDate() {
  const dateinput = document.querySelector(".date").value;
  const dateObj = new Date(dateinput);
 
  console.log("pull date", dateObj.getFullYear(), dateObj.getMonth(), dateObj.getDate());
};
```

```html
<input class="date" type="date">

<button onClick="clickDate()"> format</button>
```

you can see if you input 01/01/1900 the console outputs "pull date" 1899 11 31". Unsure what i am overlooking here.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31732581/3903479

Comment: Personally I'd just change `.value` to `.valueAsDate` and go from there.

Comment: sounds like you have a time zone issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue lies with UTC versus local timezone offsets.

Using the built–in parser, a string in the format YYYY-MM-DD is interpreted as UTC, whereas other strings will be interpreted as local.

Use of the built–in parser is discouraged:

> Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters))

On the other hand, `getFullYear`, `getMonth`, and `getDate` etc. return local values.

Here is a demonstration:

```js
  const dateInput = '2019-02-05'
  const dateObj = new Date(dateInput); // parsed as UTC
  console.log("pull date", dateObj.getUTCFullYear(), dateObj.getUTCMonth(), dateObj.getUTCDate()); // UTC
  console.log("pull date", dateObj.getFullYear(), dateObj.getMonth(), dateObj.getDate()); // local
```

You have two choices:

1) The simplest being stick with the `getUTC...` functions.

2) If that doesn't work because you need to return the date object or manipulate it, then parse the input value and construct `Date` using individual year, month, day. This works because when using this constructor, the inputs are interpreted as local.

```js
const dateInput = '2019-02-05';
let dateParts = dateInput.split('-');
dateParts[1]--; // month in Date constructor is 0-indexed (e.g. '02' represents March);
const dateObj = new Date(...dateParts); // parsed as local
console.log("pull date", dateObj.getUTCFullYear(), dateObj.getUTCMonth(), dateObj.getUTCDate()); // UTC
console.log("pull date", dateObj.getFullYear(), dateObj.getMonth(), dateObj.getDate()); // local
```

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation and examples, this was very helpful.

Comment: `new Date(...dateInput.split('-'))` returns the wrong month as months are zero indexed. In the string, "02" is February. `dateObj.getUTCMonth()` returns 2, which is March.

Comment: Nice catch, subtracting by 1 should address this.