# Subtract day in conversion between Moment and LocalDate

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript

I don't know why, when you enter a date, it give me back the same date but with one day less.

service.ts

```
  protected convertDateFromClient(project: IProject): IProject {
    const copy: IProject = Object.assign({}, project, {
      entryDate: project.entryDate != null ? moment(project.entryDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null
    });
    return copy;
  }
```

Project.java

```
...
@Column(name = "entry_date")
    private LocalDate entryDate;

public LocalDate getEntryDate() {
        return entryDate;
    }

    public Project entryDate(LocalDate entryDate) {
        this.entryDate = entryDate;
        return this;
    }

    public void setEntryDate(LocalDate entryDate) {
        this.entryDate = entryDate;
    }
```

The date entered: 12/2/2020 and return: 11/2/2020

Update: If I put the date 12/02/2020 (dd/MM/yyyy) by keyboard in the datePicker´s input, i recived from POST this 01/12/2020 (MM/dd/yyyy)

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

You might be having a problem with time zones, remember that in JavaScript Date class represent a timestamp,  is the number of miliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC.

[Mozilla Javascript Doc - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Take a look at this post for an interesting discussion, (Is the Javascript date object always one day off?)[[Is the Javascript date object always one day off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/is-the-javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off])

I have been using one of this methods to solve this issue,

```
export function dateFromModel(d: Date): Date {
  const doo = new Date(d);
  return new Date(doo.getTime() + Math.abs(doo.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
}
```

UPDATE:
I think you now have the problem I mention, plus you now are switching month and days when using moment. Just print the date before using moment and after, to check this. You can also use `toISOString()` to check what are you going to receive in the backend, this JavaScript function complies to ISO 8601 just like Java `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this problem is related to time zones. And code below works for me

```
calculateWithoutTimeOffset(date: any): Date {
  var userTimezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  return new Date(date.getTime() - userTimezoneOffset);
}
```

Comment: The problem arises on the server side