# JQuery datepicker minDate shows the date before the minimum set

Tags: jquery, datepicker

We want users to pick any date starting Nov. 30, 2020. I'm using the following script to set up the minDate on the JQuery datepicker.

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date('2020-11-30'),
  });
});
```

The problem is that when I try the picker, the first date available is November 29 instead of November 30.

[image: datepicker image]

I have tried setting different dates but the previous date is always available. However, if I set the date to 2020-12-1 then it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Run the following in the console: `new Date('2020-11-30').toISOString()`. You may be surprised by the result.

Comment: Always initialize dates using numbers when you can. In this case, use `new Date(2020, 10, 30)` (months are 0 based).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Javascript date object always one day off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/is-the-javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

> try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      startDate: new Date('2020-11-30')
    });
});
```