# Javascript new Date automatically adding one day

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a date in Javascript, but it is adding one day.

```
sDate = new Date('2020-04-01');
console.log(sDate);
```

The console output is: Date Tue Mar 31 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

Why isn't it April 1st?

Thanks

Comment: But you're _not_ creating a date. You're making JS guess at which of the 37 time zones you're talking about. So it's not an actual date until you add a time, and a timezone.

Comment: Because `GMT-0500`. Use `console.log(sDate.toUTCString())` instead.

Comment: How can I fix this GMT issue?

Comment: _by adding a time and timezone to your input_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Javascript date object always one day off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/is-the-javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off)