# How convert time in query and add time zone - date format not recognized

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to add time zone to what is returned by Oracle SQL query.

```
SELECT
    mw.appdate APPDATE
FROM
    mwo mw
```

This returns:

```
APPDATE
23-SEP-2021 00:00:00
```

I was looking at [ISO-8601 select to_char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841489/timezone-date-format-in-oracle), but I'm not sure how to apply this to my query results.

```
SELECT
to_char(mw.appdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:tze') APPDATE,
FROM
mwo mw

error:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I'm not that familiar with formatting dates.  How do I format this to add time zone (eastern standard time).

I tried

```
SELECT
    to_char(mw.appdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:est')   APPDATE
    FROM
    mwo mw
```

and it returns this error:

```
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I tried

```
mw.appdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:est'   APPDATE
```

and it adds a column called APPDATE_1 which literally has this string in it: `YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:est`

UPDATE: I want to make the query return the re-formatted date.  I can't re-insert into the db. I'm trying like is in the answer below, but it's still giving an error.

```
SELECT
   mw.account ACCT,
   mw.wono WO,
   to_char(mw.appdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AS   APPDATE
         
FROM
   mwo mw
```

ERROR:

```
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: What is the data type of column `APPDATE`? Is it already given in eastern standard time?

Comment: What is "eastern standard time"? `SELECT TZNAME, TZABBREV, TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME) FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE TZABBREV = 'EST'` returns 68 rows.

Comment: APPDATE is a date data_type in the db.  It doesn't have a time zone label.  I tried mw.appdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:est'   APPDATE, for the APPDATE line in the query and it's adding an extra column called APPDATE_1, and literally returns this YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:est.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your column is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type and is already in Eastern Standard Time then you want the format model `TZM` (not `TZE`):

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
          appdate,
          'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'
        ) AS APPDATE
FROM    mwo;
```

Then for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mwo (appdate TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);

INSERT INTO mwo(appdate) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2021-09-28 01:23:45.123456789 EST');
```

The output is:

> | APPDATE |
> | --- |
> | 2021-09-28T01:23:45-05:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=839e61ed09aff6ccaeabdb3108863ca9)*

Comment: I have a long query I wanted to make the change and return the date there.  How do I make it in my query and not in the db and reinsert?

Comment: It doesn't have time zone and anything but 00:00 for time in the table, like you do with your fiddle/insert into the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `DATE` into a `TIMESTAMP`, then you can attach a time zone and finally you can format the output:

```
SELECT
   to_char(
      FROM_TZ(CAST(mw.appdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'EST5EDT'), 
      'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:tzm'
      ) AS APPDATE
FROM mw
```

Comment: When I tried SELECT
         mw.account ACCOUNT,
         mw.wo WO,
         to_char(
         FROM_TZ_(CAST(mw.appdate AS TIMEZONE), 'ESTSEDT'), 
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM' ) AS APPDATE FROM mwo mw, I get ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 38

Comment: that select gives Typ=12 Len=7: w,c7,^C,^Z,^A,^A,^A (a long list of that)

Comment: This is from the table: APPDATE, DATE, Yes,,  12 ,,   where COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, NULLABLE, DATA_DEFAULT, COLUMN_ID, COMMENTS is the headings

Comment: A typo, sorry. Must be `CAST(mw.appdate AS TIMESTAMP)` instead of `CAST(mw.appdate AS TIMEZONE)`

Comment: I made that change  to use timestamp instead of timezone and it gives this error: ORA-00904: "FROM_TZ_": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 10

Comment: `FROM_TZ` instead of `FROM_TZ_`

Comment: I tried select 
         to_char(
         CAST(mw.appdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'ESTSEDT'), 
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'
         AS   APPDATE and it gives this error: ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Removing the extra underscore still has an error.  select 
         to_char(
         FROM_TZ(
         CAST(mw.appdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'ESTSEDT'), 
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'
         ) 
         AS   APPDATE 
         from mwo mw, has error: ORA-01882: timezone region not found
01882. 00000 -  "timezone region not found"
*Cause:    The specified region name was not found.
*Action:   Contact Oracle Support Services.

Comment: `EST5EDT` not `ESTSEDT`, check valid time zone names in view `V$TIMEZONE_NAMES`

Comment: It doesn't have an error with the EST5EDT change, but when it's showing the date on the screen, it looks like this: 2021-09-23T00:00:00-04:00.  I'm not sure what the -04.00 part is.

Comment: `-04:00` is the time zone given as UTC offset. What do you expect?