# react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker is 1 day off

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, datetimepicker

I'm so confused what's going on. I just implemented [react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker) for a user to select their birthday.

If I select June 8, 2000 -> the date returned is `2000-06-09T00:00:00.000Z`, which means the users birthday is set for June 9, 2000.

here is the element:

```
       <DateTimePicker
          value={this.props.date}
          mode={this.props.mode}
          display="calendar"
          onChange={(event, date) => {
            this.handleDatePicked(event, date)
          }}
        />

        async handleDatePicked(event, date) {
          console.log(new Date(date))
          await this.props.onSelect(this.props.propName, date)
          await this.changeState()
        }
```

`console.log(date)` logs `2000-06-09T00:00:00.000Z`

`console.log(new Date(date))` logs `2000-06-09T00:00:00.000Z`

BUT! `console.log(new Date(date).getDate())` logs `8`

And when I reopen the calendar, it is set on June 8, 2000.

My mind is exploding -- what is going on here? June 8, 2000 is only for the example - it's constantly off by 1 day no matter what day, month or year is selected. My hypothesis is something to do with timezone maybe? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This link might help many people had this issue http://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker/issues/95

Comment: @gwalshington did you solve this issue? I am getting the same behavior, but in my case, one day less.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `Date.getDate()` returns the day and month [according to local time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate). The date object you’ve provided is set to UTC time, which means when the date is converted to your local time zone it is actually the day before.

To fix this problem, [set the `timeZoneOffsetInMinutes` prop](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#timezoneoffsetinminutes-optional-ios-and-android-only) of your date picker.

Unfortunately, this prop has known implementation problems on Android. A good alternative may be to avoid the prop entirely, and instead use a date library like [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) to manipulate the time zone of the outputted date object.

Comment: The docs say that timeZoneOffsetInMinutes is known to be very buggy in Android, which is where I'm using it. Is this the only solution?

Comment: @gwalshington I’ve edited my answer to add an alternative for Android

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, but definitely confusing.

I have done my part of research and found out that this seems like a bug but it is actually not a bug.

The real issue is in how the javascript Date object parses date strings.

The best answer I have found is [this stack-O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31732581/564406). Check out its' excellent write-up.

Below is a very pertinent comment from the answer mentioned above. (credit: @Mizstik)

> All of this is due to the behavior of the underlying Date.parse() trying to follow ISO 8601. When the date string follows the yyyy-mm-dd format, it's assumed to be ISO 8601 with implicit UTC 00:00. When the string deviates from the format (e.g. mm-dd-yyyy or slash instead of hyphen), it falls back to the looser parser according to RFC 2822 which uses local time when the timezone is absent. Admittedly, this will all be quite arcane to an average person.

Now I am thinking you installed react-datetime package attached it with your input.
And then after setting your state you tried to print the date on your DOM.

But it throws an error because the react child could not be an object. So you did JSON.stringify and that is when you found out that the date is off by 1 day.

That might be happening because you are using something like this for onchange event

```
onChange={(date) => setDate(date)}
```

But that will just parse the date object as string. What you can do is use the Date object, to format the date as you would like. For instance :

```
onChange={(date) => {
    const dateString = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString()
    console.log(dateString)
}}
```

You will then get the date formatted to your locale time zone. However, if you specified a different format in your DatePicker from your local timezone format, then you can specify it as a parameter for toLocaleDateString for example:

```
new Date(date).toLocaleDateString("fr-FR")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your date time picker component add this line to resolve your issue.

```
<DateTimePicker
  { ... }
  timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={new Date().getTimezoneOffset()}
/>
```

Due to default time zone effect you are getting different date and time than yours.

Answer (score -2):

I also have this problem. I searched many documents but doesn't find a solution. So, I just implemented this in the onConfirm prop

```
const tempdate = new Date(seslectedDate);
setDate(new Date(tempdate.setDate(tempdate.getDate() + 1)));
```

Comment: This solution is not recommended as this causes problems on other timezones. I found this issue replicating after the Day Light Saving.