# Why is my Javascript new Date() object producing a date which is off by 1 day?

Tags: javascript, date

This statement:

`const date = new Date( '2022-05-04' );`

produces the following value:

> date = Tue May 03 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)

What's up with that?

How do I correct this?

TIA

Comment: It prints the date according to your machines timezone. If you want UTC then use the available UTC methods

Comment: it assumes the date is UTC. the value is adjusted for timezone -- notice it's at 5pm MST, which is 7 hours behind UTC `new Date('2022-05-04T00:00:00-0700')` returns wednesday may 4th

Comment: It creates a date-time in UTC time zone at 12 am (0 hours), and in your local time it is still the previous day.

Comment: @Jhecht unless your machine is in Pacific time ;)

Comment: How to fix this depends on the context. How is that date going to be used?

Comment: try `new Date( '2022-05-04' ).toISOString()`

Comment: It's a good question, but it has been asked many times. The JS Date object is a strange bird. Depending on how your date is formatted and instantiated, it may output either local time or UTC/GMT. This answer does a good job of explaining it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results#answer-20463521

Comment: When I created my question, none of the listed suggestions for already-answered ones were relevant.

Comment: Found this immediately by googling "js date one day off" [Is the Javascript date object always one day off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/is-the-javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off)

Answer (score -1):

The function gives the date according to your system's timezone. If you want UTC you need to mention it explicitly.
`const date = new Date( '2022-05-04' ).toUTCString();`

Similarly you can change to other timezones.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the .toUTCString() method fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use answers for comments. Your issue is that timestamps in the format YYYY-MM-DD are parsed as UTC but *toString* shows local. A more suitable solution is usually to parse the timestamp as local initially (which is consistent with ISO 8601).