# How can I combine the output of a date picker and time selector to make a single date.toISOString in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have a date selector and a time selector, and I'm trying to figure out how I can combine their outputs to make a single ISOString so that I can use with the google calendar API.
Here's what I've tried:

```
//date = 2022-05-18
//time = 14:22

const apptdate = new Date(date)
const timeSplit = time.split(':')
apptDate.setHours(timeSplit[0])
apptDate.setMinutes(timeSplit[1])
```

What I notice is when I console.log(apptdate) this is the output I get: 2022-05-17T18:22:00.000Z

I'm not sure why it changes the day from May 18 to May 17, and the time from 14:22 to 18:22.
Does anyone have a solution for this? Or even a completely different way of combining date and time to one string (other than using a datetime-local input format, I want to keep the date and time separate in my database).

Comment: Why not just string concatenation? `date + 'T' + time + 'Z'` (if the date and time are already in ISO format).

Comment: The `Date` object assumes dates and times are local unless told otherwise; see [Is the Javascript date object always one day off?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7556591/215552)

Comment: That's Heretic Monkey, this was an easy solution, I just didn't think of it (new to javascript). Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

"2022-05-18" is parsed as UTC but `apptDate.setHours(timeSplit[0])` sets the local hour. So if the host has a negative offset, the local date is 17 May and the time is set to the local hour on 17 May, not UTC hour on 18 May.

Instead use *setUTCHours* and *setUTCMinutes*.

```js
let date = '2022-05-18';
let time = '14:22';

let apptDate = new Date(date);
let timeSplit = time.split(':');
apptDate.setUTCHours(timeSplit[0]);
apptDate.setUTCMinutes(timeSplit[1]);

// 2022-05-18T14:22:00.000Z
console.log(apptDate.toISOString());
```

PS. There was also a typo: `let apptdate` then later `apptDate`.

Comment: Thank you for this info! I didn't even know setUTFHours was a thing (still learning).