# JS Date constructor is inconsistent for future dates

Tags: javascript, excel, date, constructor, office-scripts

I am doing some date manipulation in Office Scripts in Excel, and I noticed a strange behavior with dates future vs. past--I don't know if anyone else gets similar results because I can't consistently recreate this. For example, when I run the following code:

```
let d1 = new Date("2023-12-16"); // some date in the future
let d2 = new Date("2023-1-1");   // some date in the past
console.log(d1);
console.log(d2);
```

I get this output:

```
"2023-12-16T00:00:00.000Z"
"2023-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"
```

I found some great information in the discussion about the JS Date constructor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/is-the-javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off), but I still don't understand. Why doesn't the date in the future infer my time zone like it does with the date in the past? Is this yet another issue this constructor has when parsing strings?

But when I run

```
let d6 = new Date("2023-9-14");
let d7 = new Date("2023-09-14");
console.log(d6);
console.log(d7);
```

I get

```
"2023-09-14T06:00:00.000Z"
"2023-09-14T00:00:00.000Z"
```

(which also appears to be off on the time zone...)

Does it have to do with the number of characters used to specify the month?

Comment: am I right this is not about browser javascript?

Comment: UTC Date is `YYYY-MM-DD` and not `YYYY-M-D`, when an invalid date constructor to Date is used it will try and parse, and here it's then parsing as locale time instead of UTC.

Comment: @Reyno, yes, that is what the last code block is showing...same date, only "9" is replaced with "09".

Comment: For me FireFox returns the correct time zone while Chrome does not. Safari returns Invalid Date

Comment: @gog, yes; this is not browser javascript--I am editing this code in the TypeScript editor in Excel online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too difficult to explain: `2023-12-16` is a standard Javascript [Date Time String Format](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-time-string-format), and `2023-1-1` is not.

I like the summary provided by the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format), which simply says:

> There are many ways to format a date as a string. The JavaScript specification only specifies one format to be universally supported: the date time string format, a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format. The format is as follows:
>
> `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

The longer and more technical description in the ECMA-262 standard (see [`21.4.3.2 Date.parse`](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse)), says, in part<sup>1</sup>:

> The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String. The function first attempts to parse the String according to the format described in Date Time String Format ([21.4.1.18](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-time-string-format)), including expanded years. If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.

In short, when you pass a string which adheres to the Data Time String Format to the Date constructor, then it will be parsed in a very specific way, including using the UTC (commonly known as GMT) time zone.

If you use any other format, you'll get implementation-specific behavior, which often means parsing the date in the local time zone rather than UTC.

This is why `"2023-12-16"` resolves to a Date represented as `2023-12-16T00:00:00.000Z`. It is midnight of Dec 16th in the UTC time zone.

However, `"2023-1-1"` is not a Date Time String Format, so it is parsed using an implementation-specific format, which includes using the local time zone. This is why the result is a Date represented as `2023-01-01T07:00:00.000Z`... it's midnight of Dec 16th in *your local* time zone, which is 7 hours behind UTC (UTC-7), which probably means you are generating this Date in the North American [Mountain Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Time_Zone).

The string `"2023-9-14"` is likewise parsed in the local time zone, but since it's during the summer and the area you are in appears to use Daylight Savings, a summer date like this is only 6 hours behind UTC (UTC-6), so the result is `2023-09-14T06:00:00.000Z`

---

<sup>1</sup> There are caveats, such that `Date.parse()` must always result in the same Date generated by `Date.prototype.toString()` (and the value generated by `toString()` has its own [standard](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) which is quite lengthy), but it is sufficient to say that if you want to use a Date string that will be consistently interpreted by all ECMA-262 conforming Javascript implementations (which is pretty much all of them), then you should pad your month and day with zeros: `"2023-01-01"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That sure does help explain the unexpected behavior! I guess I just haven't had much experience with standard date formats. I don't know how it fits in, but the UTC-6 and UTC-7 offset that I mentioned actually occur in the same code, just a few lines apart; that result surprises me the most! (Do you know why that could happen?)

Comment: @IzekH - Since you didn't specify the time component, Javascript defaults to midnight. However, when you are using an ISO 8601 date string, it will default to midnight in UTC+0, whereas if you are not using ISO 8601, it will generally default to midnight in your local time zone. Midnight in your time zone would be 6:00 or 7:00 AM in UTC+0 (Greenwich Mean Time), depending on whether your date is in the summer or winter (due to daylight savings)

Comment: If that is what the MDN "docs" state, then it's wrong. ECMA-262 specifies 3 different formats that must be supported by [*Date.parse*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse), being those produced by *Date.prototype.toString*, *toUTCString* and *toISOString*. In addition, implementations must support the [*Date Time String Format*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-time-string-format) with missing values replaced by defaults, e.g. 2023-12 is parsed as 2023-12-01T00:00:00 and so on.

Comment: @RobG I think you've misunderstood the MDN docs. According to [`21.4.2.1 4.c.ii.2`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date), the Date constructor should parse the string exactly like `Date.parse()`. According to [`21.4.3.2`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.parse), "_If the String does not conform to that format (21.4.1.32) the function **may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats**._" Note that MDN uses the word "universally", meaning non-implementation specific.

Comment: @RobG However, I can see what you are referencing and I understand the confusion. The values generated by those functions are not "universal formats" because some elements are implementation-dependent. For example, the time zone included in `Date.prototype.toString()` is specified in [`SystemTimeZoneIdentifier (21.4.1.24)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-systemtimezoneidentifier) as being "implementation-defined", meaning you would not be able to guarantee a consistent result across different implementations.

Comment: @JDB—re your first comment, that part of ECMA-262 references *Date.parse*, which states that all 3 formats I noted must be supported. The parser first tries the *Date Time String Format*, but lower down is stated that the other two formats must be supported also. As for timezone, the offset is specified exactly (and so must be parsed identically in all conforming implementations), only the name (derived from *SystemTimeZoneIdentifier* and demonstrably different in different implementations) is implementation dependent. Its inclusion is optional, it  isn't used for parsing so is irrelevant.

Comment: @JDB—re your second comment, any implementation that does not correctly parse a string conforming to the format of *Date.prototype.toString* is not consistent with ECMA-262. It must produce identical results in all implementations because the only implementation dependant part is the timezone name, which is optional and irrelevant for parsing. Try it. Use an offset like GMT+1000 and any gibberish you like (or nothing at all) for the timezone name within the enclosing brackets.

Comment: @RobG - I don't want a debate because the standard speaks for itself. [21.4.3.2](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse) clearly distinguishes between the "[Date Time String Format (21.4.1.18)](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-time-string-format)" and everything else which are, I quote, "_implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats_". If it's not a Date Time String Format then it is, by definition, implementation-specific. You don't have to use their definitions if you don't want to, but that's the definition the standard uses.

Comment: @JDB—you can choose to interpret the spec that way if you wish. The formats of *toString*, *toUTCString* and *toISOString* are defined in ECMA-262 and therefore aren't implementation specific. *toISOString* conforms to the *Date Time String Format*, and all 3 forms must be parsed to the same number value, hence parsing of *toString* and *toUTCString* must also comply with ECMA-262.