# Google Scripts App Date returning previous month on 1st

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get the Month from a date in a cell.

Everything was working as it should until I realised.. If the date is on the 1st of the month, it will show as the month previous. For example: March 1st 2024 returns February as the month. I've tried 2 different ways of retrieving the months from the dates:

```
if(month == 0){
  monthh = "January";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "February";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "March";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "April";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "May";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "June";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "July";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "August";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "September";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "October";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "November";
}else if (month == 1){
  monthh = "December";
}


var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var monthName = months[month];

Both of these are still giving me the same issue. Am I missing something?


Edit:

The Goal is basically for finances, I input receipt data into an external app that uses google sheets. purchaseDate is the purchase date cell.

    
month = purchaseDate.getMonth();

//Check if the Month Folder Exists and Create it
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var monthName = months[month];
const monthFolderChecker = yearFolder.getFoldersByName(monthName);
let monthFolder;

if(monthFolderChecker.hasNext()){
  monthFolder = monthFolderChecker.next();
} else {
  monthFolder = yearFolder.createFolder(monthName);
}

So the goal is to get the month, check if there is a folder for that month, and if there isnt, create a folder with the Month Name. It is working fine but the 1st of the month is recording as the previous month. Could this just be a timezone issue with the Date? If so, how would I set the timezone of purchaseDate?
```

Comment: Can you provide your complete code along with a clarification with your expected result as your else if s have same conditional statements it is hard to make sense of your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Javascript date object always one day off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/is-the-javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem.  It should be an easy fix once we understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Based on the information provided, one potential issue could be a timezone mismatch between your Google Sheet and Apps Script. For instance, a date that marks the first day of the month in one timezone might represent the last day of the previous month in another timezone. To address this, ensure that both environments are set to the same timezone, or implement proper timezone handling within your code.

Comment: You don't show how you get the value of the variable `month`.  If its `Date.getMonth()` then the months are 0-11 with 0 being January.

Comment: Can you check the post I have shared above most like it is the reason for it.

Comment: @Babanana, I think I have figured it out. The timezone of my actual google sheet was totally different.

Comment: That is good to hear. Yeah, it is about the timezone as what have shared on the post I tagged on my comment.