# jQuery UI Date Picker 'defaultDate' is choosing wrong month

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a jQuery UI datepicker on my page and I set a defaultDate using the below code - but it keeps picking the month after the month I set! For example the below is showing as 1st December, not November!

```
var datePickDate = new Date(2011, 11, 01);
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: datePickDate,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        $("#datepicker_value").val(dateText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can user this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151626/4384283

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is Ok, except the fact that in javascript months are 0-based. So you should put 10 for month if you want November. Check it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)