# How to convert string to date and set as mindate in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a date string "17/02/2013" that I would like to convert to a js date object formatted @dd-mm-yy but don't know how. Any suggestions? and i need to set this date as minDate in datepicker

My JQuery Code :

```
   var time_value = result.sdate;
   var values = time_value.split("/");
   var parsed_date = new Date(values[2], values[1], values[0]);
                   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                       minDate: parsed_date
                   }); 
   alert(parsed_date);
```

In alert message

```
    Mon Mar 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: [Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date)

Comment: Try this `var s = '17/02/2013'.split('/'), d = new Date(s[2], s[1], s[0]); console.log(d);`

Comment: It Showing like this "Mon Mar 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a new Date object. You have to replace the `/` with `-` in your string because your date format (dd mm yyyy) is already correct. Only the seperator for `minDate` is wrong.

```
var time_value = result.sdate;
var parsed_date = time_value.replace(/\//g, '-');
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    minDate: parsed_date
                }); 
alert(parsed_date);
```