# Clarification on date validation in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

The confusion is to do a date validation in HTML. Is it necessary that the input type has to be "Date". Or can do the validation as input type is "text"? 
I tried following JavaScript to alert user when one date is eariler than another.
 The input field for these values type were set as "text". 
 Is there another way to do while type is "text" or do i have to change the type?

```
function checkDate(){
    var date1=new Date();
    var date2=new Date();
    date1=$("#txtStartDate").val();
    date2=$("#txtCloseDate").val();
    if(date1<date2){
        alert("The End date can't be earlier than the Start date !!");
        }
    }
```

And I am calling this function `onChange` event at date 2 input. 
From the debugger the function is calling but it's not validating.

Comment: Setting `new Date` before setting it with a string does not convert it to a date. You are comparing two strings.

Comment: Ok, that means i have to set the input type as date. No other way to do the date validation as text? (For this particular requirement)

Comment: Of course there is. Convert the strings to date

Comment: Yeah, convert the string to a date object. How to do that differs on what the user enters.

Comment: Converting String to Date : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date