# Reactjs - latest Date selection

Tags: reactjs

Am displaying array of dates. I have to pick latest date out of date array. Please suggest how i can get the latest date.

```
class SearchResultsItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr onClick={ this.handleOpen } style={{fontsize: '10',cursor: 'pointer'}}>
                <td>{ this.props.item.number }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.item.name }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.item.buyer_name }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.item.order_date ? <Moment format="DD-MMM-YYYY">{ this.props.item.order_date }</Moment> : null }</td>
                </tr>

                <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <input name="date" disabled={ this.state.mode } type="date" value={ this.state.item.date } className="form-control" onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: The latest date in which item? Comparing to what? Please provide more code and more information on what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Please find the complete code., i have to get the latest date from the date array and place it in the <input> field.

Comment: can you show us what date object looks like?

Comment: Date Object looks like this ---> 2017-09-02 (array of Date object ) stored in Mongodb as String type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution you might want to try, what it basically does is just converts the given array of strings to date object and compare.

```
    var dates = ["2009-09-09", "2017-16-07", "2001-29-01"];
    var latest = dates[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
      if (formatToDate(dates[i]) > formatToDate(latest))
        latest = dates[i];
    }

   alert(latest);

    function formatToDate(dateString) {
      var d = new Date();
      dateString = dateString.split('-');
      d.setFullYear(dateString[0]);
      d.setMonth(dateString[1]);
      d.setDate(dateString[2]);
      return d;
    }
```

Orignal answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652490/how-can-i-compare-dates-in-array-to-find-the-earliest-one)