# Can not compare date using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.I need to compare todays date with future date using Angular.js . I am explaining my code below.

```
$scope.getFutureDate = function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }
    var today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
    return today;
}

$scope.addPlanData = function() {
    var today = $scope.getFutureDate();
    if (today < $scope.date) {
        alert('Please select todays date or previous date');

    }
}
```

Here my requirement is when todays date will less than future date it will show me the alert message.In this code its happening only within the month.But if i will compare with like this `30-11-2015 with 1-12-2015`,its not showing any alert message.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manipulate string to create date.

Try this

```
$scope.addPlanData=function(){
 var today= new Date();
 if(today < new Date($scope.date.split("-").reverse().join(",")){
            alert("Please select today's date or previous date");
        }
}
```

It gives you alert when user select future date which is greater than today. If you want alert when user select past date then use `>` in if condition.

Comment: @subhra while this works, you should still consider to write a parse function for that date-format if you need it in other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.addPlanData=function(){
 var today= new Date();

 var dateArray = $scope.date.split("-");
 $scope.date = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1] - 1, dateArray[0]);

 if(today < $scope.date){
            alert('Please select today or previous date');
        }
}
```

The relational operators `<` `<=` `>` `>=` can be used to compare JavaScript dates.

Comment: @ VVK : `$scope.date` ,I am getting date from calender.

Comment: and i am also getting like this format `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: its a sting because i am using datepicker.

Comment: No,its changing my date format and also not checking.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

When you compare dates as strings, the comparison takes one char at a time, and because in your example 3 is greater than 1 (even if `30-11-2015` is a smaller date than `1-12-2015`), the result is greater for the november date. If you want to stick to string representations of dates, change the format of date to `YYYY-MM-DD`, so that you'll have the year compared first, then the month, then the day. In this situation you'll have `2015-12-01` greater than `2015-11-30`, because the comparison will stop at the `2` from the units digit of the month.

```
$scope.getFutureDate = function () {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if ( dd < 10 ) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    } 
    if ( mm < 10 ) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    } 
    return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
}

$scope.addPlanData = function () {
    var today = $scope.getFutureDate();
    if ( today < $scope.date ) {
        alert('Please select todays date or previous date');
    }
}
```

## Solution 2

You can compare dates directly. In this care you need to cast your `$scope.date` variable to `Date` format by `$scope.date = new Date($scope.date)` and compare it with `new Date()`. This method gives you less code, as you don't need the `getFutureDate` method.

```
$scope.addPlanData = function () {
    if ( new Date() < new Date($scope.date) ) {
        alert('Please select todays date or previous date');
    }
}
```

Comment: @ iulian : But my insert date format is `dd--mm-yyyy`.Will it be fine ? I will prefer solution 1.

Comment: what datepicker module do you use? if you use the datepicker from angular-ui-bootstrap, you can specify the date format you would like the date to be in. although I think the actual value is a `Date` object, isn't it?

Comment: i am using `720kb.datepicker` and i need the format `dd-mm-yyyy` finally.

Comment: @subhra Try my answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to parse a Date from a custom format (`dd-mm-yyyy`).
I'd recommend to use a dedicated function to parse that date format, especially if you need to parse that kind of date format in more than this case:

```
function parseDate(dateString) {
    var date = new Date();
    // reset time to 0:00:00
    date.setUTCHours(0);
    date.setUTCMinutes(0);
    date.setUTCSeconds(0);

    var parts = dateString.split("-");
    date.setUTCDate(parts[0]);
    date.setUTCMonth(parts[1]);
    date.setUTCFullYear(parts[2]);

    return date;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$scope.addPlanData = function() {
    var today = new Date();
    if (today < parseDate($scope.date)) { // parse custom date format here
        alert('Please select todays date or previous date');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to do the same.

Convert the string to date using regular expression and then use `< or > or <= or >=` to compare.

```
$scope.compare = function() {
   var date1 = "30-11-2015";
   var date2 = "1-12-2015";
   var d1 = new Date( date1.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3") );
   var d2 = new Date( date2.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3") );
   alert(d1 < d2);
  };
```

Reference: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151626/967638)