# Javascript Date Convert

Tags: javascript, web

I am currently trying to convert a dd/mm/yyyy string to a date so i can compare it to another date.

The string, for example, is 16/12/2015 but when i use the below code to convert it to a date it just gives random months / years for example 19/11/1902.

Here is the code:

```
date = (date.substring(0, 6) + year);
var dsplit = date.split("/");
var myDate=new Date(dsplit[0],dsplit[1]-1,dsplit[2]);
```

in that above code dssplit[0] is 16, next one is 12 and the last one is 2015 - im not sure why it is doing this.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date

Comment: @Gaz Smith is the below the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the below:

```
    var date = "16/12/2015";
    var dsplit = date.split("/");
    var showDate = new Date(dsplit[2], dsplit[1] - 1, dsplit[0]);
    alert(showDate)
```

Please see the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3dg21adb/) demonstrating this

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong order of arguments:

```js
var date = '16/12/2015';
var dsplit = date.split('/');
var myDate = new Date(dsplit[2], dsplit[1]-1, dsplit[0]);
alert(myDate);
```