# Convert date format from object containing dates in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How to convert above all the date into `YYYY-MM-DD` format? I have used this way but it's not working.

```
$scope.dateDatas = [0:"29-09-2016", 1:"30-09-2016",2:"01-10-2016",3:"02-10-2016",4:"03-10-2016"]

angular.forEach ($scope.dateDatas, 
            function (value) {
            var d = $filter('date')(value, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
            console.log(d);
          });
```

Comment: because they are not date objects, you need to have dates in your data source

Comment: How can you put the `key`, `vaule` pairs in an array `dateDatas`?

Comment: @Angular_10 no they don't have to be in  the source...but they do need to be parsed to dates to use the filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$scope.dateDatas = ["29-09-2016", "30-09-2016", "01-10-2016", "02-10-2016", "03-10-2016"];
$scope.result = [];

angular.forEach ($scope.dateDatas, function (value) {
    var splitValue = value.split("-");
    var date = new Date(splitValue[2], splitValue[1] - 1, splitValue[0]);

    var res = $filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    $scope.result.push(res);
    console.log(res);
});
```

Here are the issues:

1. On the first line, the there shouldn't be any pairs in an array, remove the 'key', and keep the value:

   `$scope.dateDatas = ["29-09-2016", "30-09-2016", "01-10-2016", "02-10-2016", "03-10-2016"];`
2. As a side note, remember also to put semicolon after the array.
3. `$filter('date')` will work on dates, not on strings. You first need to convert your initial string to a date object. I got the code to convert this string to Date from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151607/520229). Also note that you need to decrease the month value by 1 before passing it to `Date` constructor because month in `Date` constructor is 0-based for some reason (expects 0 for January, 1 for February etc):

   `var splitValue = value.split("-");`
   `var date = new Date(splitValue[2], splitValue[1] - 1, splitValue[0]);`
4. The filter parameter should be `'yyyy-MM-dd'` instead of `'yyyy-mm-dd'` (capital M's), because small m's represent minutes instead of months and will give you this result:

   `["2016-00-29", "2016-00-30", "2016-00-01", "2016-00-02", "2016-00-03"]`

Also check full example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8NIGsBOj3o6FP2GsyVIQ?p=preview).