# Format date d-m-yyyy to leading zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Hello I got a question regarding formatting a date where the days and months have a leading zero if the date does not have a leading zero, for example in cases of: 1-1-2017.

Now I tried to code some code based on different answers here on Stackoverflow but without succes.

Here is my code:

```js
var input_date = "1-1-2017";
var input_date2 = "22-11-2017";

var myDate = new Date(input_date);
var prettyDate =
    ( '0' + (myDate.getDate()) ).slice( -2 ) + '-' + 
    ( '0' + (myDate.getMonth()+1) ).slice( -2 ) + '-' +
    myDate.getFullYear();


document.write( prettyDate );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this works for dates as: 1-1-2017 but whenever the variable `input_date2` is used as Date parameter then the formatting goes wrong.

I am looking for a mechanism which formats my date if the leading zero is missing. Any help would be appreciate it.

PS. Actually, I was wondering would this not be easier with jQuery instead of using plain Javascript as I did above?

Comment: You don't mention your locale, but 1-1-2017 is pretty unambiguous whilst 22-11-2017 could be being parsed as the 11th day of the 22nd month. Just avoid this date format unless you really, *really* need to, and use yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Your code works fine, the problem is the date format. Your date is `DD-MM-YYYY`. The `Date()` object only accepts `MM-DD-YYYY` or `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the format of your date string.  `Date()` uses the following format: `MM-DD-YYYY`.  If you change `input_date2` to use this format then it works fine.

```js
var input_date = "1-1-2017";
var input_date2 = "11-22-2017";

var myDate = new Date(input_date2);
var prettyDate =
    ( '0' + (myDate.getDate()) ).slice( -2 ) + '-' + 
    ( '0' + (myDate.getMonth()+1) ).slice( -2 ) + '-' +
    myDate.getFullYear();


document.write( prettyDate );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

This function "filters" the values and add the '0' only if day/month are < 10  (5 to 05 for example) there is plenty of room for improvement... Sorry the first one didn't work at all.

```
function fixDateFormat(input_date){
        let myDate = new Date(input_date);
        //document.write(myDate + " ----------- ")
        let myDay = myDate.getDate();
        //document.write("Day: " + myDay + "| ");
        let myMonth = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
        //document.write("Month: " + myMonth + "  ::::  ");
        myDay = (myDay < 10) ? ("0" + myDay) : myDay;
        myMonth = (myMonth < 10) ? ("0" + myMonth) : myMonth;
        return myDay + "-" + myMonth + "-" + myDate.getFullYear();
    }


    var input_date = "1-1-2017";
    var input_date2 = "22-11-2017";

    var prettyDate = fixDateFormat(input_date);

    document.write(prettyDate);
```

I test it and now it return the dd-mm-yyyy format you want.