# Why is date from CSV file being outputted as NaN?

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

I've just finished a video on Lynda.com and can't get the same results the instructor gets using D3. I've created a simpler version of the files in question, and it still doesn't work. The console outputs NaN when I try to retrieve a date.

The CSV, as output from Excel, is:

```
Date,AM
1995-04-16,3.5
1995-04-17,14.0
1995-04-18,10.8
```

and the Javascript file contains:

```
d3.csv("bg_test_date_parsing.csv", function(d) {
  return {    Date: +d.Date,  AM: +d["AM"]  };
}, function(data) {
    console.log(data[1]);
});
```

The console in Mozilla gives me:

```
Object { Date: NaN, AM: 14 }
```

I can't proceed with any projects because I don't know where to start with importing dates properly. Videos on lynda.com just keep going, and I still don't get how to import and format dates. Also, the CSV originally was formatted 16-04-1995 as an example, outputted from a medical instrument, and I manually typed it into a year-month-day format that apparently D3 will work with. It took me many hours already using Google to get this far, so I'm obviously missing some key understanding.

Comment: Okay I see my CSV data didn't appear as intended. It's `Date,AM` followed on the next line by `1995-04-16,3.5` and so on, for about 8 lines of data.

Answer (score 4):

`+d.Date` isn't working the way you want. Calling `+` on `16-04-1995` is resulting in `NaN`. You can't convert that string to a number like that.

You can convert the string like this, `var myDate = new Date('04-16-1995')`

Unfortunately, your format is day-month-year, and javascript wants month-day-year.

See this question for what to do about that:

[Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date)

---

**Update** As @GerardoFurtado notes in his comment, the `d3` library has some built in date parsing options that can convert dates in different formats. See the links in his comment.

Using `d3`, you could convert the string to a Date like this:

`var myDate = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y")('16-04-1995')`

or, within your loop:

`Date: d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y")(d.Date)`

Comment: If you want to edit your answer to make it a complete one: D3 **can** parse a "day-month-year" string, check here: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#d3-time-format . Here is a fiddle showing how to do it, feel free to copy it to your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/gyvp0t0k/