# Not getting validate after convert to data in JS

Tags: javascript

I have one string `"09-04-2000"`. Now I am trying to convert it into date using `JS Date()`.

```
var parseDate= new Date("09-04-2000"); Format : DD-MM-YYYY
```

After executing above code I am getting output : `Mon Sep 04 2000 00:00:00` which is wrong.

What is the correct way to get correct result in JS?

Comment: Either change your date's format to parseable one, or use a lib like moment and provide the correct format for the date

Comment: oh, right, so 09-04-2000 represents 9th April - rather than re-inventing the wheel ... try using momentjs library

Comment: Also note: that code will result in `InvalidDate` in firefox - so, I would recommend testing what you finally do in more than just one browser (Chrum, I'm guesding)

Comment: or ... `new Date("09-04-2000".split('-').reverse().join("-").concat('T00:00:00.000Z'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do in following way :

```
var dateString = "09-04-2018"
var birthDate = dateString.split("-");
birthDate = new Date(birthDate[2], birthDate[1] - 1, birthDate[0]);
```

Get reference from [Click for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) or if you want a simple solution you can try the following:

```
function getDate(str){
    var splits = str.split('-');
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(+splits[0]);
    date.setMonth((+splits[1])-1);
    date.setYear(+splits[2]);
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use pure js,that is not so convenient like `to_date(str,'dd-mm-yyyy')`,try `moment.js`

```js
let str="09-04-2000";//dd-mm-yyyy
let args=str.split(/-/g).reverse();
args[1]--;
console.log(new Date(...args));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var today = new Date(); 

var dd = today.getDate(); 
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!  
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();  

if(dd<10){ dd='0'+dd; }  
if(mm<10){ mm='0'+mm; } 

var today = mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy; 
document.getElementById("DATE").value = today;
```