# How to convert date format into different formate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I want to convert

```
March 2018 to 032018
```

in jQuery.I used

```
var  d = new Date($('.selected_month').find("td:first").text());
```

But it is giving result is:

```
Thu Mar 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Comment: `March 2018 to 032018 ` this  your date ?or it's your required result ?

Comment: my  date is March 2018 and i want result like 032018

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getMonth()` and `getFullYear()` on returned date object to format date as per requirement. Also, you need to add 1 to returned month as getMonth method is 0 index based:

```
(d.getMonth()+1).toString() + d.getFullYear().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),    
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;   

    return [month,year].join('');
}
```

Call this function : `formatDate('March 2018') // output : 032018`

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the date object you end up with to a string:
Try the following snippet, just change `var  d = new Date()` to `var  d = new Date($('.selected_month').find("td:first").text())`.

```js
var  d = new Date();
var twoDigitMonth = (d.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
var result = twoDigitMonth + year;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

...or try this...

```js
console.log(
    new Date("March 2018")
    .toLocaleDateString('en-EN', {month: '2-digit',year: 'numeric'})
    .replace('/','')
)
```