# new Date('dd/mm/yyyy') instead of newDate('mm/dd/yyyy')

Tags: javascript, date

Is it possible to enter date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format into `newDate` (e.g. 03/01/2018) so that it returns object `Wed Jan 03 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) {}`?

If I have a date `03/01/2018` it returns `Thu Mar 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) {}` instead... I'm not trying to pass `mm/dd/yyyy` format..

I've looked at plenty of posts on this and can't find an answer to my question.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151607, just replace the `-` by `/`.

Comment: Why you couldn't use the pattern mm/dd/yy?

Comment: @חיים פרידמן because I'm working with a database full of those dates

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk Are they stored as strings or dates? As you'd be better of using ISO 8601.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no control over the Date constructor, so you need to feed it a date in the format that it wants. Since you are formatting the date yourself, it is better to use the other Date constructor, which takes the year, monthIndex, and day as arguments, since it is more bullet-proof across different browsers and runtimes:

```js
  function my_date(date_string) {
      var date_components = date_string.split("/");
      var day = date_components[0];
      var month = date_components[1];
      var year = date_components[2];
      return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    }
    
    console.log(my_date("03/01/2018"));
```

The case of **dates** one area where I install the `moment` library on nearly every JavaScript project I create.

Note: Snippet may display the result differently; check your console.

Comment: This is not about the Date constructor *per se*, but about the parser.

Comment: Well RobG it's certainly better than your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex like so:

```
var date = new Date("03-01-2018".replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"))
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to parse a string to make another string that must be parsed again. After the first parse, you can pass the parts directly to the Date constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use momentjs from http://momentjs.com/ . it is very easy to use to output any format u want.

```html
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // June 28th 2018, 10:30:09 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Thursday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jun 28th 18
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2018 escaped 2018
moment().format();
```

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.