# How to convert a dd/mm/yyyy string to a date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have used to convert to date format.

```js
var date1 = "28/01/2019"
var d = new Date(date1)
console.log(d)
```

I am getting invalid date as output. Kindly help

Comment: What's in `date1`?

Comment: date1 is a variable where I have stored the actual date of string type

Comment: @LakshmiG what they are asking is what is the format of the date string. i.e `04/01/2019` or `Jan 16, 2019 2:00p` etc.

Comment: this is the value stored in date1  "28/01/2019";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert dd/mm/yyyy string into JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299687/how-to-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-javascript-date-object) and [new Date('dd/mm/yyyy') instead of newDate('mm/dd/yyyy')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085176/) and [Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enter the date in the format of `"01/28/2019"` for it to be a valid date string which can be parsed. You can do this using `.split()` to manipulate the string around.

See example below:

```js
var date1 = "28/01/2019".split('/')
var newDate = date1[1] + '/' +date1[0] +'/' +date1[2];

var date = new Date(newDate);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151607/10221765)

```js
var date1 = "28/01/2019".split("/");
var d = new Date(date1[2], date1[1] - 1, date1[0]);

console.log(d);
```