# DatePipe.transform show InvalidPipeArgument for 'dd-MM-yyyy'

Tags: angular, typescript, date-pipe

Recently Angular DatePipe is showing an InvalidPipeArgument error but the String date seams to be correct.
Can any one see some error?  this is my code using **Typescript** and **Angular 6**

```
let datePipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe("es-ES");
let dia_sele: string = "";
                try {
                  let fecha_formateada = this.datePipe.transform('23-01-2019', 'dd-MM-yyyy','es-ES');
                  dia_sele = fecha_formateada;
                } catch (e) {
                  dia_sele = "";
                  console.log( "->err:" + e);
                }
```

And this is the error showing in console from Chrome Windows:

```
core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "23-01-2019" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "23-01-2019" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4013)
    at DatePipe.transform
```

Comment: I feel like there is some confusion. Datepipe is usaly used to format a date into a specific datestring. Why are you using a string of the same format that you would expect to recieve from the transform function? [Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Because your input and output date have the same format.

But the solution that will work if you need date in another format

**Why it is not working??**

In chrome `'23-01-2019'` is not a valid date string. Even

```
new Date('23-01-2019')
```

gives `Invalid Date` message in chrome (not checked in other browsers). You may try in console.

**Solution**:

So alternatively you may format the date with some other separator say `/` and then perform `DatePipe` transform on that date. More on formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date/7151626)

Example :

```
let myDate = "23-01-2019".replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")
let newDate = this.dp.transform(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'es-ES');
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-pipe-format-error?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer, in my example I'm using a string date into '' only to explain the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try this code for datetime-local type

```
this.myDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.myDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss');
console.log(this.myDate)
this.form.patchValue({date_of_spent:this.myDate});
```

2. Try this peace of code for date type

```
this.myDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
console.log(this.myDate)
this.form.patchValue({date_of_spent:this.myDate});`enter code here`
```

Comment: TKS!! Very good. In adittion, for that work, i added in app.module.ts
import localeArg from '@angular/common/locales/es-ES';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
registerLocaleData(localeArg);