# Calculation Future dates with number of days

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, adobe, adobe-javascript

Can someone help with script for Adobe pdf.

I got 3 text field

```
Start Date
Number of Months
End Date
```

So I want a script when i populate Start date and Number of months, automatically populate the end date

example

```
I enter start date= 1/12/2018

then i enter Number of months= 2

the output should be= 2/02/2019
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: @Basil Bourque: *argh* I should have read used tags more carefully before answering ;-). Answer deleted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date