# jQuery validate dynamic month and day inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having troubles of using jQuery validation to validate dynamically generated month and day inputs. Basically, I want to make sure certain months could not have more than 30 days, and Feb. could not have more than 29 days. My approach works well when the month and day inputs are fixed. I appreciate any suggestions. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/322f2/).

#### HTML

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action=index.html>
    <table class="tab tab_Application" border="0">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="id_noa">Number of Applications:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <select name="noa" id="id_noa">
                    <option value="">Make a selection</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='noa_header' style="display:none">
            <th>App#</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Mass Applied (kg/hA)</th>
            <th>Slow Release (1/day)</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <tr>
        <input type="submit" />
    </tr>
</form>
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('valid form submitted');
            return false;
        },
        rules: {
            noa: "required"
        }
    });


    var i = 1
    $('#id_noa').change(function () {
        var total = $(this).val()
        $('#noa_header').show()
        while (i <= total) {
            $('.tab_Application').append('<tr class="tab_noa1"><td><input type="text" size="5" value="' + i + '"/></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="mm' + i + '" id="id_mm' + i + '""/></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="dd' + i + '" id="id_dd' + i + '""/></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="ma' + i + '" id="id_ma' + i + '""/></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="sr' + i + '" id="id_sr' + i + '" value="0""/></td></tr>');
            i = i + 1;
        }
        while (i - 1 > total) {
            $(".tab_Application tr:last").remove();
            i = i - 1
        }

        $('</table>').appendTo('.tab_Application');

        $('[name*="mm"]').each(function () {
            $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                monthCheck: true
            });
        });

        $('[name*="dd"]').each(function () {
            $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                dayCheck: true
            });
        });

    });

    ////define validation functions    

    $.validator.addMethod(
        "monthCheck",

    function (value) {
        return mmCheck(value);
    },
        "Please enter a right month");

    $.validator.addMethod(
        "dayCheck",

    function (value, element) {
        return ddCheck(value, element);
    },
        "Please enter a right day");

    function mmCheck(value) {
        var mmValue = value;
        if (mmValue < 1 || mmValue > 12) return false;
        return true;
    }

    function ddCheck(value, element) {
        var mmValue1 = $(element).closest("tr").find('input').val();
        var ddValue1 = value;
        if (ddValue1 < 1 || ddValue1 > 31) return false;
        else if (mmValue1 === 2 && ddValue1 > 29) return false;
        else if ((mmValue1 === 4 || mmValue === 6 || mmValue1 === 9 || mmValue1 === 11) && (ddValue1 > 30)) return false;
        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: Something is very wrong with your jsFiddle and I cannot figure it out.  The way you've constructed it, it should either fail validation or show the alert... however it does neither and just redirects to another page.  This usually means that the Validation plugin is not liking your code even though it passes jsHint.

Comment: @Sparky Yes. I followed your suggestion and validated a static month and day input fields, which works, however, once I implemented it dynamically, something wired happened... Could it be the local variable and global variable issue?

Comment: I found a problem in your code that adds a extra `"` quotation mark within every `input`.  Just examine the rendered HTML in your DOM inspector and you'll see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed three problems in your jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vMW37/11/

1)  Removed the extra duplicate quotation marks within your cloned `input` fields.

2)  Added a `name` attribute to your first `input` field.  Even though it's not validated, it still must contain a `name` attribute.

3) Syntax error in this line, notice the `mmValue === 6` is missing the `1`...

```
else if ((mmValue1 === 4 || mmValue === 6 || mmValue1 === 9 || mmValue1 === 11) && (value > 30))
```

**NOTES**:

This line is incorrect so any subsequent logic using `mmValue1` is failing unexpectedly.

```
var mmValue1 = $(element).closest("tr").find('input').val();
```

Try this:

```
var mmValue1 = $(element).parent().prev('td').children('input').val();
```

Comment: Is it possible the dynamic loop breaks the validation rule?

Comment: @tao.hong, I think I found all the critical errors... see my edited answer.  Validation is working as expected now... it's just up to you to tweak the logic.

Comment: @tao.hong, focus all of your attention on this line: `var mmValue1 = $(element).closest("tr").find('input').val();`... make sure it's the proper value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for, but [here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800253/check-date-in-javascript) to a different stackoverflow post that explains how to validate dates in JavaScript.

Basically, whenever you're dealing with dates in any language you want to try to use built-in date libraries.  JavaScript's date library is unfortunately pretty awkward, but it's still available, your ddCheck function would turn into something like this:

```
function ddCheck(value, element) {
    var mmValue1 = $(element).closest("tr").find('input').val();
    var ddValue1 = value;
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var dateEntered = new Date(currentYear, mmValue1, ddValue1);

    return dateEntered.getDate() == ddValue1 && dateEntered.getMonth() == mmValue1 && dateEntered.getFullYear() == currentYear;
}
```

Also there's an error with line 1 of ddCheck, when it selects the month input.

```
var mmValue1 = $(element).closest("tr").find('input').val();
```

This selector is not specific enough, you are always returning the value of the first field, which is the app number, for your month.  You could either add a class to the month so the code looks like this:

```
var mmValue1 = $(element).closest("tr").find('.j-month').val();
```

or you could use a [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select by the id.

*edit:  I removed the triple equals from the return because I didn't want to include integer validation in this example as well.

Comment: Thanks Dave! But I had similar validation for a fixed month-day input, which works.. It is really wired.

Answer (score 1):

Remove one extra equal to i got it fixed!!

$.validator.addMethod(

```
    "dobday",
    function(value,element){
        return ddCheck(value, element);
    }



);
function ddCheck(value, element) {
    var mmValue1 = $('#edit-month').val();
    //alert(mmValue1);
   // var dayval = $('#edit-date').val();
    var ddValue1 = value;

    if (ddValue1 < 1 || ddValue1 > 31) return false;
    if (mmValue1 == 2 && ddValue1 > 29) return false;
    else if ((mmValue1 == 4 || mmValue1 == 6 || mmValue1 == 9 || mmValue1 == 11) && (ddValue1 > 30)) return false;
    else         return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Previous I messed up with `var mmValue1 = $('#edit-month').val();` and Sparky helped me to fix that.