# Сode execution on a specific date (Java Script)

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why now date is 11 july 2020 but next code is doesn't work:

```
var GivenDate = '2020/07/11';
var CurrentDate = new Date();
GivenDate = new Date(GivenDate);

if(GivenDate == CurrentDate) {
  alert('NOW');
}
```

Comment: what makes you think the two would ever be equal?

Comment: Because I set date what I need and current date. I fount this example in Web.

Comment: just extract the year month and date using getYear, getMonth, getDate, etc and compare with that.  or use a substr of the locale string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800253/check-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Your current date `CurrentDate` includes the time and even the locale. Your given date doesn't and this defaults to 00:00:00 for the time and whatever local timezone. Further, you're comparing objects and since they are separate instantiations, they will never be equal even if they contain identical properties. ........... This is they "why" @solanki... solution works (below) while your's doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To check whether given date is equals to current date or not***

```js
const isToday = (date) => {
  const today = new Date();
  return date.getDate() === today.getDate() &&
    date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
    date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear();
};

console.log(isToday(new Date('2020/07/14')));
console.log(isToday(new Date('2020/07/11')));
```